# How to make an array of CRect objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, mfc

I want to define an array of `CRect` objects in a header file. So will it be something similar to this:

```
  #pragma once
  #include<atltypes.h>

  CRect blockPos[3] = { CRect(0,0,55,43),  CRect(0,0,55,43), CRect(0,0,55,43), };
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the need. Do the elements only have meaning in the context of a certain class, and is the intention that the elements won't change? If so a static const member of the class might be what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is intended to be constant, then you could simply declare the array `const` in the header:

```
CRect const blockPos[3] = { CRect(0,0,55,43),  CRect(0,0,55,43), CRect(0,0,55,43), };
```

This does mean that each translation unit that includes the header will generate its own copy, which might not be ideal if the array is very large.

If it is not constant, or you want to avoid multiple copies, then you will need a single definition for the whole program, and just a declaration in the header:

```
// header
extern CRect blockPos[3];

// some source file
CRect blockPos[3] = { CRect(0,0,55,43),  CRect(0,0,55,43), CRect(0,0,55,43), };
```

In this case, beware of the *static initialisation order fiasco*. It's not specified when this will be initialised relative to global variables in other translation units, so your program might have undefined behaviour if the constructor of another global variable tries to access it. In general, global variables are fraught with peril, so use them with extreme care.

Comment: Note that the static initialization order fiasco can be avoided in this case by using the Win32 data type `RECT`, which is just POD, instead of the MFC type `CRect`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define a variable in a header file as it will be defined multiple times at the sites where you include the header file. You should use an accessor method instead:

Header file

```
#pragma once

CRect* GetRectArray();
```

C++ file

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

namespace
{
    CRect blockPos[3] = { CRect(0,0,55,43),  CRect(0,0,55,43), CRect(0,0,55,43), };
}

CRect* GetRectArray()
{
    return blockPos;
}
```

Comment: You can still declare a variable as external in the header file, and define it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You can do, but I was using a more C++ approach, based on his example using MFC.

Comment: why do you place it in a namespace?

Comment: and by the way, the elements of this array will be `const` because they're actually the positions of some rectangles drawn in the client area. So isn't there a better and more organized way of defining it, keeping the purpose in mind?

Comment: The namespace here is an anonymous namespace, which is recommended rather than using the static keyword.